# Space of self-dual connections

Tags: differential-geometry, principal-bundles, hodge-theory, exterior-derivative

Let $(M,g)$ be a 4-dimensional Riemannian manifold and $(P,M,\pi)$ a principal $G$-bundle over $M$. Denote by $ad (P)$ the adjoint bundle of $P$, that is, the vector bundle obtained by dividing $P\times  Lie(G)$ by $G$ with the right action $(p,\xi)\mapsto (p\cdot g, Ad(g^{-1})\xi)$.

There is a Hodge star operator for the $ad(P)$-valued 2-forms:
$$\star:\Omega^2(M,ad(P))\to\Omega^2(M,ad(P))$$
This is a symmetric isometry and its eigenvalues are $\lambda=\pm 1$. The corresponding eigenspaces will be denoted by $\Omega^2_{\pm}(M,ad(P))$.

The connection 1-forms $\omega$ of $(P,M,\pi)$ whose curvature form $\Omega^\omega$ belongs to the eigenspace $\Omega^2_+(M,ad(P))$ are called *self-dual*. We will denote by $\tilde{\mathcal M}(P,g)$ the set of self-dual connections.

I am trying to prove the following:

> **Claim.** $\tilde{\mathcal M}(P,g)$ is an infinite dimensional Hilbert submanifold of $\mathcal A(P)$, the (Sobolev complection of) the set of curvature forms

For do so, I propose to use following result:

> **Subimmersion Theorem** (Theorem 3.5.17 of [1]) Let $f:M\to N$ be a smooth map between two Hilbert manifolds and $q\in N$. If $f$ is a subimmersion in an open neigbbourhood of $f^{-1}(q)$. Then $f^{-1}(q)$ is a submanifold of $M$ with $T_pf^{-1}(q)=\ker d_pf$, $p\in f^{-1}(q).

Let us consider the curvature map $$C:\mathcal A(P)\to \Omega^2(M, ad(P)),\,\omega\mapsto C(\omega)=\Omega^\omega$$
Then, if we compose with the projection $\Omega^2(M, ad(P))\to \Omega^2_+(M, ad(P))$ we obtain a map $C^+:\mathcal A(P)\to \Omega^2_+(M, ad(P))$ such that its preimage $(C^+)^{-1}(\{0\})$ coincides with $\mathcal M(P,g)$.

By the definition of subimmersion, it is sufficient to show that $C$ is a submersion. However, this is not the case because its differential $C_{\star \omega}$ coincides with the exterior differential $d_\omega:\Omega^1(M,ad(P))\to \Omega^2(M,ad(P))$, which is not surjective.

Thanks in advance.

### References

[1]  R. Abraham , J. E. Marsden , T. R. Manifolds, *Tensor Analysis, and Applications*. Applied Mathematical Sciences (AMS, volume 75). Third Edition.

Comment: I am slightly confused: the space of self-dual connections is not the preimage of $0$ through $C^+$... We are interested in the connections $\omega$ satisfying $\star\Omega^\omega-\Omega^\omega=0$, so maybe the right thing to consider would be the preimage of $0$ through the map $\omega\mapsto\star\Omega^\omega-\Omega^\omega$. Does this make sense?